# Speed up geolocation query

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, geolocation

i tryng to implements a geolocation query that search over the products (150.000) in a table that have latlng id_product and id_categories, and the query run very slow . This is the query:

```
$prodottip = \App\Models\Prodotti::join('products2sellers', 'products2sellers.id_prodotto', 'prodotti.product_id')->where('prodotti.id_tipologia', 'PRODUCT')->join('aziende', 'products2sellers.id_seller', 'aziende.Id')->select('prodotti.*', 'aziende.*')->whereRaw('match (prodotti.nome, prodotti.categoria_composta, prodotti.descrizione_lunga) against (? in boolean mode)', [$cosa])->selectRaw('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                           cos( radians( products2sellers.lat ) )
                           * cos( radians( products2sellers.lng ) - radians(?)
                           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                           sin( radians( products2sellers.lat ) ) )
                         ) AS distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])->OrderBy('distance', 'ASC');
```

any suggestion to speed it UP?

This is the dump of the 3 table.
I'm on MariaDB but i have also installed MongoDB.

```
CREATE TABLE `aziende` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contatto` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `visualizzazioni` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `categoriapg` varchar(130) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `titolo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'verrà utilizzato come nome aziendale',
  `sottotitolo` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'slogan aziendale',
  `immagine` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `IndirizzoGeolocalizzato` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'email ufficiale',
  `telefono` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'telefono ufficiale',
  `sitoweb` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'sito web ufficiale',
  `visualizza` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `scadenzacontratto` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ultimouser` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ragionesociale` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `piva` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `codfisc` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `agente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Provincia` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Citta` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attiva` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_utente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `entry_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `descrizione_azienda` longtext NOT NULL,
  `tag_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tag_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `coupon` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sconto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `partner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lat` double NOT NULL,
  `long` double NOT NULL,
  `regione` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `nazione` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `via` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cap` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `condizioni_vendita` longtext NOT NULL,
  `condizioni_spedizione` longtext NOT NULL,
  `cellulare` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_piano` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `citta_fatturazione` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `via_fatturazione` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `civico_fatturazione` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `stato_fatturazione` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cap_fatturazione` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `provincia_fatturazione` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `regione_fatturazione` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `lat_fatturazione` double NOT NULL,
  `long_fatturazione` double NOT NULL,
  `indirizzo_fatturazione` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_civico_fatturazione` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `numero_civico` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `sla1` float NOT NULL,
  `sla2` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='aziende promotrici';

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `prodotti`
--

CREATE TABLE `prodotti` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipologia` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `categoria_principale` varchar(110) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `immagini` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_produttore` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_unita_misura` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prezzo` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `link_statico` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attivo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_visualizzazioni` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantita_magazzino` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `backorders` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codice_sku` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pagamenti_abilitati` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `spedizioni_abilitate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tags` text NOT NULL,
  `tag_title` text NOT NULL,
  `tag_keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `tag_description` text NOT NULL,
  `id_gruppi_utenti` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `vetrina_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_acquisti` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `thumbnail` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `quantita_minima` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_tasse` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descrizione_breve` longtext,
  `descrizione_lunga` longtext,
  `negozio` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `prezzo_scontato` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `alternativi` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `immagine_principale` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `sottocategoria` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_abbonamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_acquisto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `featured` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bicolors` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genere` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_id` varchar(110) DEFAULT NULL,
  `barcode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prezzo_acquisto` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `univoco` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `season` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `showcase` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `optimized` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `materiale` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `peso` float NOT NULL,
  `model_qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fornitore` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `madein` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoria_composta` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `products2sellers`
--

CREATE TABLE `products2sellers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_prodotto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_seller` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `taglia` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colore` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` double NOT NULL,
  `lng` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indici per le tabelle scaricate
--

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `aziende`
--
ALTER TABLE `aziende`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `prodotti`
--
ALTER TABLE `prodotti`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indici per le tabelle `products2sellers`
--
ALTER TABLE `products2sellers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per le tabelle scaricate
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `prodotti`
--
ALTER TABLE `prodotti`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=52102;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `products2sellers`
--
ALTER TABLE `products2sellers`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=52101;COMMIT;
```

Basically i can structure this as well using eager loading but i suppose that the results is the same. Also i can try to use some geolocation/plugin in MariaDB but i need some suggestion

Comment: FYI MariaDB and MongoDB are essentially two different storage systems. Assuming MariaDB/MySQL, do you have any indexing in place on your columns? Can you post your migrations or a dump of your table structure including indices?

Comment: Added a dump. I'm using a plugin on Laravel that use MongoDb in eloquent syntax so the structure is the same.

Comment: I am not sure if the indices are missing from your dump or if you have none. You should add an index to the columns you're querying, this will speed up your queries significantly. A general rule of thumb would be to add them to columns that form part of your `WHERE` statements and any columns that are using in a `JOIN`,

Comment: That's a bulky table.  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Answer (score 0):

"Find nearest" has 3 speeds:

- Painfully slow due to computing the distance to *every* item and finding the closest.
- Possibly OK -- using a "bounding box" and a suitable index.
- Fast -- but the code is complex.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

The solution must be coded at the MySQL/MariaDB level.  Laravel may need to use raw SQL to get at it.

(It won't answer the Question, but *do* use InnoDB, not MyISAM.)